# Command that setsup a text channel for the guild

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I want to make a command that sets up a channel in a server how do i do it? It this correct cause it keeps giving me errors,

**Code:**

```
@Bot.command()
async def azsetup(ctx, guild, channelName):
    await guild.create_text_channel('cool-channel')
    
    embed = discord.Embed(title='', description=f"Setup is Done:" , color = discord.Color.green, timestamp=ctx.message.created_at)
    embed.add_field(name="Note:" , value ="All the Modlogs and Important Announcements will be set there!")
    await ctx.send(embed = embed)
```

Comment: what error is it giving?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not defining the command right, `guild` is already included in `ctx`.
The `*,channelname` to make everything after the command as the channelname

```py
@Bot.command()
async def azsetup(ctx, *,channelName):
    await ctx.guild.create_text_channel(channelName)
```